# Query Builder vs Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have been hearing that the built-in query builder for the Entity Framework is much faster than Linq to Entities. Is this true? If so, can I use the query builder for any type of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries don't execute any faster, if that's what you mean.